# How to return a plain object from a cypress api call?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I use cypress for testing api calls. I have functions which make api calls and return a Chainable like this `Cypress.Chainable<Cypress.Response<SomeClass>>`. Here, SomeClass can be a custom class or simply object type. I want to create a function which will return a custom class instead of a Chainable. Is that possible in Cypress? How to do it?

```
function getCar(model) : Cypress.Chainable<Cypress.Response<<Car>>{
  return cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api url"
    body: {model}
    headers: the headers
  });
}
```

I'd like to return Car instead of the above return type, as shown below. How to do this in Cypress?

```
function getCar(model) : Car{
  //the code.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have asynchronous code like `cy.request()` you can't easily get back to a synchronous value like the Car object.

The options are:

- Use `.then()` after your function

  ```js
  getCar(model).then(car => {
    ...
  })
  ```
- Wrap the request in a Promise and await it

  ```js
  function getCar(model) : Cypress.Chainable<Cypress.Response<<Car>>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "api url"
        body: {model}
        headers: the headers
      })
      .then(response => 
        const car = ... // extract car from response
        resolve(car)
      })
    })
  }

  it('gets Car', async () => {
    const car = await getCar(model)
  })
  ```
- Use Mocha before or beforeEach blocks to set up a global (handles awaiting for you)

  ```js
  let car;
  before(() => getCar(model).then(result => car = result))

  it('uses Car', () => {
    // use car variable (in scope)
  })
  ```

Other variations of the last include

- using an alias (but these are cleared between tests)
- setting a `Cypress.env('car')` variable (ugly syntax and fails if page resets).